# Using the Windows 7 and DirectX SDKs with VS2005

Tags: visual-studio-2005, directx, winapi

I have Visual Studio 2005 and want to teach myself DirectX in my free time. I downloaded the latest Windows 7 and DirectX SDKs. According to Microsoft's website, the latest DirectX SDK is not compatible with Visual Studio 2005 (I assume they mean it's not compatible with the SDK it came with). Can I configure VS2005 to use the SDKs I downloaded instead of the SDK it came with? If so, is there anything I should be particularly careful with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The June 2010 DirectX SDK no longer supports Visual Studio 2005.  You need to download an older version of the SDK and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I'd wager you can encourage June 2010 to run under 2005.  You may need to modify your headers slightly to make them 2005 compatible but the DX DLLs don't care what they get dynamically linked to by ... Install the SDK set up the include and library paths to point at the DirectX sdk ... compile and see what errors you get.